# CSS: float content next to a table

Tags: css

I'm trying to float some content left, with a table to the left-hand side.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TxLyr/1/

I'd like the text content that's currently below the table to be to the right of the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Full CSS for reference:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.table-container {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: none;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#aside { 
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: You have  to give a `width:38%` on id `aside.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it:

```
#aside { 
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:39%; /* this line added */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TxLyr/9/

and you can use 40% but if you have border or padding you must use `box-sizing` and it's need `css3`.

and `box-sizing` Compatibility here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=boxsizing

Answer (score 2):

You've to set a proper width value for the `#aside` element.

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TxLyr/4/)

Since you have a border of `1px`, you cannot set the width to `40%;`. Set it to `39%` or remove the border.

You have to set the width of course. If you don't the element takes it's auto width.

```
#aside { 
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:39%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a width `38%` on id `#aside`.  Here using 38% width because you are using a `1px border.` Also to clear float property you have to use `overflow:hidden` property.